# Log in to an external website and redirect it as a logged-in user

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

great pleasure someone helps me with the following question, you will see I want to create a site that stores the accounts of the external pages, so that when they enter the user and the password in my application, this one realizes the login in the external web and then redirect the page how logged in users. My question is this, is it possible to do that? I wanted to try it with guzzle, but it could not, then I tried goutte, but I got an error that did not detect the fields, what could I do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So users will need to share their username and password with you and you'll be storing that in your DB, and it'll need to be plain text or in a way that is easily converted back into plain text. This is a BIG RED FLAG.

If there is some legitimate reason why you'd be doing this, I'd suggest working with a CookieJar in Guzzle. You could POST a login with the user credentials, and store the resultant cookie, then send that in the headers with any subsequent request for that user.

Some rough code to give you an idea:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
$filename = $somePath . '/cookies.json';
$jar = new GuzzleHttp\Cookie\FileCookieJar($filename);
// Login
$url = 'http://some_login_url';
$body = [
    'user' => $someUser,
    'pass' => $somePassword
];
$response = $client->post($url, ['cookies' => $jar, 'body' => $body]);
// Make sure the response is valid here
$jar->save($filename);
// Retrieve a private page for a user
$url = 'http://private_page_url';
$response = $client->get($url, ['cookies' => $jar]);
// Make sure the response is valid here
$html = (string) $response->getBody();
// Do scrapy stuff with HTML
```

Clearly, this would need a bit of work to make it useful.

Comment: I understand, I only have one question, once the account is sent with guzzle, the user could enter directly to the protected pages of the external website without asking for the login?

Comment: I mean precisely after sending the username and password, redirecting it to the protected pages of the external website and that you no longer need to log in

Comment: @MarcosDavidHuarangaOrtega - if the cookie data allows access to protected pages, any request made with the cookie data will be able to access the protected pages. The above code will save the cookie on a server and allow the server to access the pages.